# Flutter desktop app for MacOS using extra binaries crashes when exported

Tags: flutter, flutter-desktop

I want to distribute a Flutter desktop app outside of App Store. The app includes some extra binaries using the `assets` key in pubspec.yaml. The binaries end up in this directory inside the app:

```
flutter_sample.app/Contents/Frameworks/App.framework/Versions/A/Resources/flutter_assets/bin
```

So that's what I use with `Process.run(...)` and it works locally. However, if I try to notarize the app in Xcode and export it then app will crash immediately when trying to run an included binary. I opened Console and found the following entry in launchd.log corresponding to the time the app crashed:

> 2022-01-07 08:28:04.875197 (gui/501/application.com.example.flutterSample.1772919.1772925) : removing job: caller = runningboardd
> 2022-01-07 08:28:04.875204 (gui/501 [100020]) : removing service: application.com.example.flutterSample.1772919.1772925
> 2022-01-07 08:28:04.875309 (gui/501/application.com.example.flutterSample.1772919.1772925) : internal event: PETRIFIED, code = 0
> 2022-01-07 08:28:04.875311 (gui/501/application.com.example.flutterSample.1772919.1772925) : job state = removed

I wasn't able to find any other information about the error. If I enclose the code using `Process.run` in a try-catch block it doesn't change anything, the entire application crashes anyway. The same happens if I use a zone or onError handler as described on the [handling errors page in Flutter docs](https://docs.flutter.dev/testing/errors).

Extra details:

- I've disabled com.apple.security.app-sandbox in the *.entitlements files, with it running the processes didn't work even locally
- I've enabled hardened runtime in Xcode, it was required to notarize the app.
- the app also crashes if instead or exporting from Xcode I plainly archive the build directory (with `tar`) and send it via internet (or set `com.apple.quarantine` with `xattr`). It won't crash if I just pack and unpack it without marking it as quarantined. That makes sense but I expected that notarizing the app would fix it.

So, what can I do to prevent these crashes, or at least get more details when they happen so I can investigate further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, it was an issue with paths. If I go to my project directory and then enter the debug build directory:

```sh
$ cd build/macos/Build/Products/Debug
```

then from this point I can access two identical asset directories:

```sh
$ ls -lh App.framework/Versions/A/Resources/flutter_assets
(output omitted)

$ ls -lh flutter_sample.app/Contents/Frameworks/App.framework/Versions/A/Resources/flutter_assets

(the same output, omitted)
```

As it turns out, I was actually trying to call the binary in the first asset directory (even though I posted the second one in the question). And apparently the other one is correct when the app is packaged for distribution. After changing this the binaries work in the exported, notarized app.

Comment: congrats! the bounty cannot be awarded to yourself and is not refundable. do you think my answer is also helpful

Comment: Your answer was worth trying, thanks, but ultimately it didn't solve the problem or make it easier to find the solution. If someone runs into the same problem and finds this thread, I think it might be confusing if they see the bounty went to one of the answers even though it didn't solve the problem. So I'll just let it expire.

Comment: Sure, no problem. "ultimately it didn't solve the problem or make it easier to find the solution" - indeed for someone else sometimes my solution is the only approach or the suggested approach for multi platforms ;) And IMHO accepted answers are at the top.

Answer (score 0):

Try to firstly *copy* your binary from assets folder to somewhere else. Let's say copy to `/tmp/myfile`. Then ensure you have executable permission to it (`chmod +x /tmp/myfile` using shell; should have sth similar using code). Then execute that binary.

This is a common practice, at least for platforms like Android. Because in android, an asset does not have a "normal" path so you have to copy it out, IIRC.

If this method works, it is great; even if not, now you can manually call `/tmp/myfile` in a shell to see what is happening.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it was worth a try. Unfortunately it didn't solve the problem. The app wasn't able to copy the binaries to /tmp. I also tried getTemporaryDirectory() from the path_provider package, but that didn't work either.

Comment: "The app wasn't able to copy the binaries to /tmp. I also tried getTemporaryDirectory() from the path_provider package, but that didn't work either." -- That may not happen, or your permission setting is wrong. You may create a separate Stackoverflow question and link it here. This suggestion should solve the problem after you can copy the files

Comment: I was able to get it to work yesterday. I need to check a few things, I'll get back to this question in a day or two.